# Code theory question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

An RSA crptosystem has modulus $n = 253$, and you wish to send a message m = 31 to your friend whose public encoding key $e = 17$. What encoded message $m'$ do you send?

No clue how to do this question and i need to do  a bunch like them. In their working out they go from 'observe that $e = 16 + 1$' to $31^2 ≡ -51   \pmod{253} $ and i'm not sure how they made this leap. Thanks.

Comment: Are you certain that they do not continue after that? Because $31^{16+1} = (((31^2)^2)^2)^2\cdot 31$ is probably the fastest way to calculate that power (this method is called "repeated squaring").

Comment: @Arthur Yes they do it about 4 or 5 times, but i'm not sure how they did it the first time and got -51?

Comment: That's because $31^2 = 961 = 4\cdot 253 - 51 \equiv -51 \pmod{253}$.

Answer (score 0):

The two statement you mention are just for building up to their evaluation of $31^{17}$.

First statement: $e=16+1$ this is obvious from arithmetic.

Second statement: note that $31^2=961=1012-51=4\times253-51\equiv-51\pmod{253}$

The method for encoding is as follows:

The encoded message $m'$ is found via:

$$m'=m^e\pmod{n}$$

Hence for the question:

$$m'=31^{17}$$

$$=31^{16}\times31$$

$$=(31^2)^8\times31$$

$$\equiv(-51)^8\times31\pmod{253}$$

$$\equiv((-51)^2)^4\times31\pmod{253}$$

$$\equiv2601^4\times31\pmod{253}$$

$$\equiv71^4\times31\pmod{253}$$

$$\equiv(71^2)^2\times31\pmod{253}$$

$$\equiv5041^2\times31\pmod{253}$$

$$\equiv(-19)^2\times31\pmod{253}$$

$$\equiv361\times31\pmod{253}$$

$$\equiv108\times31\pmod{253}$$

$$\equiv3348\pmod{253}$$

$$\equiv59\pmod{253}$$